# Pandas: How do I create a new column given the column values exist in a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

What's the neatest way to create a new column based on the values from another column being contained in a list of lists with some extra conditions as well?

So the dataframe and the nested list are:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ "col": ["A", "B", "D", "G", "C", nan, "H"]})

categ = [["A", "D"], ["Missing", "C"], ["Other"]]
```

In my case I would also like np.nan to be considered as "Missing" and if the column value is not present in the lists then it should be considered as "Other".

So the resulting df should like this:

```
   col        NewCol
0    A        [A, D]
1    B       [Other]
2    D        [A, D]
3    G       [Other]
4    C  [Missing, C]
5  NaN  [Missing, C]
6    H       [Other]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop to check if the column row is in the list.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

result = []

for row in df.values: 
    for i in range(len(categ)):
        if row in categ[i]:
            result.append(categ[i])
            break
        elif i == len(categ) - 1:
            result.append(process.extractOne('Other',categ)[0])
            break
        elif pd.isna(row):
            result.append(process.extractOne('Missing',categ)[0])
            break

df['NewCol'] = result

   col        NewCol
0    A        [A, D]
1    B       [Other]
2    D        [A, D]
3    G       [Other]
4    C  [Missing, C]
5  NaN  [Missing, C]
6    H       [Other]
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this is helpful. I have a number of columns each with a corresponding nested list, and not always 'Missing' is contained in the 2nd sublist or ['Other'] is the 3rd sublist. Can this be more generalisable?

Comment: I should have said that for eg Missing for some columns it can be bundled with other values: such as ["Missing", "C"] for col1 and ["Missing, "A", "F"] for col2.

Comment: In this case, you can use `fuzzywuzzy` to get the desired match :) does this work for you now, @Sam?

Comment: If it works for you, please mark the answer after you have tested it ;)